# How to increment lines in excel even these lines are separated?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

How do I increment values in excel if the data exists else the increment has to stop until the next cell which has data?

This picture shows you what I want to have:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean if the cell in column B is not blank then display a number in Col A incremented from the last value in Column A?

Comment: yes i mean that

Comment: It's easy if a hidden column is used to keep track of the current "last value" in column A, it probably requires VBA if your going to reject a hidden column as part of the solution.

Comment: I have found a solution, I inserted a column in the begenning, in the column A I test the cell C1 if empty I put blank "" if not I put 1, and in column B I tested if A1 is empty I put blank if not I put this sum : sum($A$1:A1), and it's done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type a formula

```
=IF(LEN(B1)>0,COUNTA(B$1:B1),"")
```

in `A1` and drag/copy it down:

[image]